# How to select text scale of > 175% on a 3840 x 1100 secondary monitor?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, scaling

I have a Windows 10 Version 22H2 (build 19045.3324) laptop with 3 monitors:

1. The primary builtin monitor, 3840 x 2162, 16.5"
2. A secondary builtin ScreenPad monitor, 3840 x 1100, 14"
3. An external monitor, 3840 x 2162, 32".

For the first two monitors I would like to use a fairly large scale of 200-250%, and for the third I would like to use less aggressive scaling of 125%.  So I navigated to "Settings" => "Display" and selected each of the first two monitors.  For monitor 1, Windows 10 offers scales from 100% to 350%, but for the second monitor, **it only offers scales up to 175%**:

| Monitor 1 (3840 x 2162) | Monitor 2 (3840 x 1100) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: scales from 100% to 350%] | [image: scales from 100% to 175%] |

How can I make Windows 10 offer additional scales for the 3840 x 1100 monitor?

**What did not work**

I selected the second monitor and went to "Advanced scaling settings".  There were two options including "Custom scaling", the latter of which stated, "All your displays will be set to the custom scaling size you enter."  I only want the first two monitors to be scaled to 250%, but I tried it anyway.

[image]

After being forced to sign out and back in again, unfortunately **all three monitors** were set to some large scale -- reportedly 350%:

[image]

Since this is not what I wanted, I canceled custom scaling.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I change Windows 10 Display Scaling Programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35233182/3744182) on SO.